# R: autolayer moving average gives error

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting

I want to plot a time series together with its moving average like the example in [a Forecasting: Principles and Practices](https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/moving-averages.html) I use my own time series called `salests`:

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2015 110 115  92 120 125 103 132 136 114 139 143 119
2016 150 156 130 169 166 142 170 173 151 180 184 163
```

I then use similar code as in the book:

```
autoplot(salests, series="Sales") +
  forecast::autolayer(ma(salests, 5), series="5 Moving Average")
```

But I receive the error:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems that I just am following the book.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas that could help you.

```
# I start reading your dataset
df1 <- read.table(text='
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2015 110 115  92 120 125 103 132 136 114 139 143 119
2016 150 156 130 169 166 142 170 173 151 180 184 163
', header=T)

# Set locale to 'English' if you have a different setting
Sys.setlocale( locale='English' )

# I reshape your dataset in long format
library(reshape)
df2 <- melt(df1)
df2$time <- paste0("01-",df2$variable,'-',rep(rownames(df1), ncol(df1)))
df2$time <- as.Date(df2$time, "%d-%b-%Y")
( df2 <- df2[order(df2$time),] )

#        variable value       time
# 1       Jan   110 2015-01-01
# 3       Feb   115 2015-02-01
# 5       Mar    92 2015-03-01
# 7       Apr   120 2015-04-01
# 9       May   125 2015-05-01
# 11      Jun   103 2015-06-01
# 13      Jul   132 2015-07-01
# 15      Aug   136 2015-08-01
# 17      Sep   114 2015-09-01
# 19      Oct   139 2015-10-01
# 21      Nov   143 2015-11-01
# 23      Dec   119 2015-12-01
# 2       Jan   150 2016-01-01
# 4       Feb   156 2016-02-01
# 6       Mar   130 2016-03-01
# 8       Apr   169 2016-04-01
# 10      May   166 2016-05-01
# 12      Jun   142 2016-06-01
# 14      Jul   170 2016-07-01
# 16      Aug   173 2016-08-01
# 18      Sep   151 2016-09-01
# 20      Oct   180 2016-10-01
# 22      Nov   184 2016-11-01
# 24      Dec   163 2016-12-01
```

Now create a time-series `ts` object

```
( salests <- ts(df2$value, frequency=12, start = c(2015,1)) )
#   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# 1 110 115  92 120 125 103 132 136 114 139 143 119
# 2 150 156 130 169 166 142 170 173 151 180 184 163
```

and plot it:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(forecast)
autoplot(salests)  +
  forecast::autolayer(ma(salests, 5), series="5 Moving Average")
```

[image]

Comment: I think the trick (at least for me, and which I worked out from your post-  thanks!) was to detach ggfortify and forecast and then reattach ensuring ggfortify is attached PRIOR to forecast.  Although not necessary for printing objects from forecast package I was using for survival plots

Comment: @user1420372 Thank you for your suggestion!